# How to find out what SMTP port you are using?

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp, smtpclient

How do i find out what SMTP port the corporation i work for has set up for it's email server? 
I've tried searching for it via outlook but it doesn't give me the option.

I'm looking for an answer that i'll be able to do via cmd.

Posting this question here so future individuals who are in my position will know what to do

Comment: Why don't you simply ask them?

Comment: Lets say its Friday and all the IT people have gone home or your IT person doesn't even know what SMTP means

Comment: If your IT guy does not know about SMTP, it's time to find a new one. But besides that: how is this question related to programming after all, and why did you tag it with `jenkins`?

Comment: I agree with your IT statement. It's related to jenkins because i'm currently trying to get Jenkins to send an email to individuals when a build is started

Comment: Sorry, but searching for the SMTP port is neither related to Jenkins nor to programming after all

Answer (score 1):

The default SMTP port for most mail servers is port 25; either that or port 587 if you are using explicit SSL. If you are using implicit SSL, then it is port 465. You should be able to discover the port through Outlook; here is an article: https://www.doteasy.com/domain-email-and-website-hosting-articles/how-to-update-your-smtp-port-ssl-settings-and-smtp-authentication

Comment: It says i need to click on "Outgoing server" but i don't have that option.

Comment: If you can't contact your colleagues, you can always contact your ISP or just simply experiment with each of the three ports I mentioned, or even port 2525. Again, your best bet is port 25 for mail servers to mail servers. If not and you are using client-server email authentication, consider ports 465 and 587.

Comment: I've been trying ports, i've tried 25, 26, 465, 587, 2525, 8080, 442, 80. So i've tried quite a few, was wondering if there was actual method to find this out.

Answer (score -1):

If like me you work for a large company, the issue is that IT are blocking the ports. You need to go and have a word with the IT department to get it fixed.